# Extract URL From Excel Hyperlink Formula using xlwings

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

I have an Excel file with hundreds of cells that use the Hyperlink formula =HYPERLINK( ,  ). I need to convert this hyperlink formula in to  URLs required for further operations.

Can i do it using xlwings as I am already using xlwings for other operations in same excel.

if any one can share some idea will be grateful[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1JeN.png)

[image]

Comment: In this case its just a formula so use `ws['D2'].formula`